# Joining two tables in phpadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have to join two tables in PHPMyAdmin. One is called `tracks`, the other one is `album`
I select from `album`: album_name, year, album_number. Both tables have `track_id` column. I use that code:

```
SELECT `album_name`,`year`, `album_number`
FROM `album`
JOIN `tracks` ON tracks.track_id=album.track_id
```

And it returns me the result, only from the album table, it does not join the other table, tracks. Where is my mistake?

[example of that query]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT93m.png

Answer (score 1):

you are doing a the join and only selecting three columns, album_name, year,album_number
so the results are of only 3 columns, try adding album.track_id in your select to look like this.

[refer here on joins](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

SELECT `album_name`,`year`, `album_number`,album.track_id
FROM `album`
LEFT JOIN `tracks` ON tracks.track_id=album.track_id

or if you want to get all the columns in both tables do this, I hope one of this will work

SELECT *
FROM `album`
LEFT JOIN `tracks` ON tracks.track_id=album.track_id

Answer (score 0):

The first option returns me only columns from the album table, those 3 plus track_id. Nothing from the tracks table.

The second one I already tried and it works, but I don't need to see all the columns of both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all fields from the tables on SELECT statement

`SELECT  album.*, tracks.* FROM album JOIN tracks ON tracks.track_id = album.track_id`